# Confused SQL Order

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT
    date(created_at as date) as created_date,
    id,
    count(distinct file_name) as files_total,
    null as files_error
FROM table
GROUP BY created_date, id
```

I do not have a columns called `created_date` anywhere in my table.

Why does this query work?

```
Created_Date
```

is created when taking the date of created_at, in the select part of the query.

SQL is processed in this order:

```
from, where, group by, having, select, order by
```

`Group By` comes before `Select`.

In the query above, the alias didn't come until after the g`roup by`, but for some reason, the alias works in the `group by`.

Why is this?

Comment: I don't really understand the question here - you seem to have answered it yourself: it works because `created_date` is the alias defined in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: edited my post to clarify

Comment: Ah, I see; I guess the key distinction is between *logical order of processing*, and *alias visibility*, since an alias only needs to be expanded to its full form (here `GROUP BY date(created_at as date), id`) by some pre-processing step. I'd be interested to see a well-referenced answer that explained exactly what Postgres's alias visibility rules are (and how they might vary in other DBMSes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a column named `created_date`, but you have created a alias name `created_date` here

```
date(created_at as date) as created_date,
```

In postgresql, alias names can be referred in `Group by` that is why it was working

Logically `Group by` clause might be processed after the `select` though it is not the case in all the `DBMS`

Comment: They might be used in `Order by` clause also.

Comment: PRDP: Thank you. That answers my quesiton.